# Не работает virtulenv

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

Библиотеки устанавливаются в системную папку питона, несмотря на то, что venv активирован и используется интерпретатор виртуальной среды

Comment: Запускаете установку в том же терминале, в котором активировано виртуальное окружение? Если устанавливаете через pycharm, добавьте скриншот окна настройки интерпретатора, в котором будет видно, что для проекта выбран интерпретатор именно из виртуального окружения.

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Добавьте информацию о ОС и что используете как virtualenv (существуют разные опции)